# Why octave figure closed very soon in emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, ubuntu-14.04, octave

I use `GNU Emacs 24.3.1` on `Ubuntu 14.04` and I have a simple `octave` script which it's name is `test.m`:

```
#! /usr/bin/octave -qf
x=1:10
plot(x);
```

When I try to execute that by `M-! ./test.m`, an empty figure window appears but closed very soon and I saw this result in `emacs`:

```
warning: function ./test.m shadows a core library function
x=

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Why do you think I have to change the name?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama OK! But I renamed script previously. It's name was `t.m` and the same message was appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is really just that: Your function file test.m shadows the built in function `test` but as long as you don't want to call the built in `test` function you can ignore it (although it's considered bad practice to shadow core functions).

The plot disapears because octave exits after running test.m. You have to call Octave with --persist or it's common to add a `pause` at the end of the script which waits for a keypress:

```
#! /usr/bin/octave -qf
x=1:10
plot(x);
pause
```

Comment: @Andy I used `pause(10)` and it solved the problem of figure window. Please edit your answer.